# After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on desktop, I can't login anymore

Tags: dual-boot, login

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on desktop, I'm able to see GRUB, I can select and enter into Ubuntu, but there is only a purple or black background with a cursor, and sometimes I can login.

Comment: Did you used CD as your installation medium or a USB pen drive?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to install 16.10. I just did a reinstall with a disk wipe and that worked. Im sure you could wipe your ubuntu partition if you decide to do a reinstall.